# JsonParseException on Jsonrpc4j client

Tags: java, client, jsonrpc4j

I'm trying to create a client with jsonrpc4, but I always have a  JsonParseException error. 
I've tried many things, simple client.invoke and dynamic proxy, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Here is my code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            String username = "****";
            String password = "****";
            String cred = Base64.encodeBytes((username + ":" + password).getBytes());

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(1);
            headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + cred);

            JsonRpcHttpClient client = new JsonRpcHttpClient(new URL("https://dms1.ok.by/api/v1/json­rpc"));
            String elem =  client.invoke("myMethod", new Object [] {"param"}, String.class);

        }
        catch(Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.HttpException: stream is closed at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient.invoke(JsonRpcHttpClient.java:161) 
    at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient.invoke(JsonRpcHttpClient.java:185) 
    at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient.invoke(JsonRpcHttpClient.java:110) 
    at net.nameshield.registryapi.monRobot.main(monRobot.java:38) 
     Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') 
    at [Source: com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.NoCloseInputStream@1184ab05; line: 1, column: 2] 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:456) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2689) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:878) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:772) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3834) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3783) 
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2908) 
    at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.ReadContext.nextValue(ReadContext.java:25) 
    at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcClient.readResponseNode(JsonRpcClient.java:312) 
    at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcClient.getValidResponse(JsonRpcClient.java:246) 
    at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcClient.readResponse(JsonRpcClient.java:194) 
    at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcClient.readResponse(JsonRpcClient.java:531) 
    at com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.JsonRpcHttpClient.invoke(JsonRpcHttpClient.java:159) 
... 3 more
```

Comment: I can't even figure out which client.invoke you are calling http://briandilley.github.io/jsonrpc4j/javadoc/1.4.3/com/googlecode/jsonrpc4j/JsonRpcHttpClient.html not seeing one with 4 parameters with a class at the end... but I suspect it's new Object [] {"param"}... what are you trying to pass to it?

Comment: My mistake, I don't pass "domain" in client.invoke(), it's a misprint.